Understanding a Protocol: Consistent Bytes and MAC Address Verification
My client A sends a request to server B. Server B then responds with a 24-byte response. This response is sent by client A to server C, where server C checks the response. This mechanism is used for MAC address verification, and I’m trying to understand how the protocol works. I’ve written a sample implementation that sends two requests and receives responses.
Here are the results:
CD 70 46 2B F7 E1 65 12 0D E2 25 8C F2 5D 26 31 0D 86 26 07 F2 3E 25 A0
C4 D1 E0 2B 28 69 E9 46 0D 3D 25 85 F2 82 25 90 0D 59 25 A1 F2 E1 26 28
After waiting some time…
FE 7A FA 9D 11 B7 B5 2C F4 E1 25 BF F4 C7 26 3B 0B 4C 25 BB F4 BC 25 F6
3E 65 66 9D 9E 21 FC 9B F4 6E 26 7F F4 48 26 24 0B C3 26 27 F4 33 26 60
As you can see, there are consistent bytes at the same positions in each request, and the “magic” bytes 25 and 26, which could potentially be boolean values or something similar. I’ve tried brute-forcing XOR and other methods, but to no avail.
I suspect that this request contains a MAC address that is verified by server C, as server C sends network interfaces with all data, including hardware addresses. Can anyone provide insights into how this protocol might work?
